# how to obtain a HttpWebRequest range in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

im doing a project where I should take half of the image from one source and another half from another source and then merge them together.

in c# it works like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
request1.AddRange(0, 10000);
HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL2");
request2.AddRange(10000, 20000);
```

and then I read the streams, merge them into a buffer, and write the buffer into a file.

now I have to create a plugin that does the same thing,
as far as I know that I can create an extension for firefox with javascript.

do you think that is possible to do the same thing in javascript or I should search another method? I dont even know yet how to create a plugin so I dont know if I can use some programming language(maybe I can even use c# or java to directly create a firefox plugin)
can you give me some tips? thanks a lot

Comment: what are you trying to do a bit more exactly? Anyway manipulation streams in JavaScript is not really possible. A plugin like plupload uses either POST; Silverlight or Flash injected proxies; to manage data streams. Also, you could use jQueries `$.get`, `$.load` or `$.post` but its nothing more than AJAX(more what you want) or POST

Comment: I need a plugin that listen for http connections, so whenever im downloading a file, it download first the header and if it match some requisites than sends a request to another server that works like a tracker(torrent server).   and then download only part of the file from the main server and other parts from other clients that will upload that file....   basically a plugin that transform client-server architecture in peer to peer

Comment: You would need two services/handlers to handle that.. and your client will only do some simple ajax with an object to tell it what to do.(in my mind that is the easy way and most secure) but please do tell more cause the answer to the question needs more details.. even if oyu use another example

Comment: ok what do I need is this:  everytime I download something, the plugin must download the header first, then take the URL/name/dimension and send everything to another server that sent back a list of other clients who already have that file.  at that point the plugin will start to download a part of the file from the URL and other parts from other clients, and then merge them together.  (like a torrent file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can definately do it with ajax

Here you are

[Link](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1506/range-requests-with-ajax/)

```
 $(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'range-test.txt',
    headers: {Range: "bytes=618-647"},
    success: function( data ) { $('#results').html( data ); }
  });
});
```

Comment: cool! can you please read also my last comment and tell me if is something that I can actually do in ajax? cause if you tell me that is possible im gonna start learning how to create firefox extension in ajax

Comment: Well I have no idea about firefox extensions, but since they certainly can do a lot more than normal javascript I see no reason why it should not be possible. May I ask you why do you not just use c# and choose to make a plugin for FF? It seems to me that this projects is much better suited for a powerfull language like c# or java and not for js

Comment: oh that's because I need it as an automatic tool inside the browser... if I made it it c# than I need everyclient to run my application, but if it's just an extension everyone owns a browser ^^